# Linux mint 19.1 cinnamon randomly didn't boot after update - just once however

Tags: boot, software-updates

After running some updates on linux mint 19.1 cinnamon, i shut down my PC. When i went to boot it up again, the screen stayed black, however the fans of my PC were running. After doing a force shut-down during this failed boot process, i was afraid that the updates might have somehow lead to my PC being unable to boot up at all.
However, i tried it again right after, and everything worked fine.

What could have been the reason of said behaviour? If it happened right after updating, should i still roll back my system with timeshift to reinstall said updates, even though everything works just fine again now?

Answer (score 0):

Semiconductor devices are not perfect; a transistor in an integrated circuit failed to work correctly. Whether a spike that got through the power supply and surge protector, a marginal junction, cold solder joint, or cosmic ray impact (don't laugh; a beta particle is just a free electron), if it does not repeat, count your blessings and move on.